# Volume and surface area of a fourth degree superellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, 3d, solid-geometry

I was browsing through pages on Wolfram Mathworld, and I came through this interesting page about the '[Rectellipse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rectellipse.html).' The page had formulas for the area and perimeter of the shape in two dimensions with the equation: 
 $x^4+y^4=1$ 
I was wondering how one could calculate the volume and surface area of the same shape in 3D ([3D Rectellipse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20x%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bz%5E4%3D1)), with the equation:
 $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$ 
I couldn't come up with much so I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

don't know about surface area, the volume in the first octant  is
$$ \frac{ \Gamma \left( \frac{5}{4} \right)^3}{\Gamma \left( \frac{7}{4} \right)}  $$
so the whole figure has volume
$$ \frac{ 8 \; \Gamma \left( \frac{5}{4} \right)^3}{\Gamma \left( \frac{7}{4} \right)}.  $$

My calculator says this is about $6.481987,$ smaller than the cube of edge two $8,$ but bigger than the sphere of radius one $4.18879.$

Method was published by [Dirichlet, article title: Über eine neue Methode zur Bestimmung vielfacher Integrale](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99435r/f394)

Comment: Hey could you tell me the page numbers for the same? Thanks!

Comment: Also do you have an alternate link because the one in the answer isn't very legible?